# Unable to save Entity with OneToMany mapping using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Order` and `OrderLineItem` with `One-to-Many` relationship. When I am saving the Order, I am getting ConstraintViolationException. Below is the code snippet.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Order extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    private long orderId;

    private double price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",
            fetch = EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Set<OrderLineItem> orderLineItems = new HashSet<>();


    // scaffolding code
    public void addOrderLineItem(OrderLineItem orderLineItem){
        this.orderLineItems.add(orderLineItem);
        orderLineItem.setOrder(this);
    }
    ... setters, getters, toString, equals and hashcode methods
}
```

In `OrderLineItem` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_line_item")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OrderLineItem extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Order order;

    public OrderLineItem(String name, double price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public OrderLineItem(){}
    ... setters, getters, toString, equals and hashcode methods
}
```

OrderServiceImple class

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public Order createOrder(Order order) {
        System.out.println("Inside the save method of Order service .... :: ");
        System.out.println(order);

        return this.orderRepository.save(order);
    }
    ...
}
```

OrderRepository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    List<Order> findAll();
}
```

I am using `OrderRepository` and  `OrderItemRepository` JPA interfaces.

The post request

```
{
  "price": 4500,
  "orderLineItems": [
     {
       "name": "new Order Item",
       "price": 4000
     }
   ]
}
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'order_id' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you share the code where you save those entities?

Comment: there is no implementation for OrderLineItemService. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Lemmy Updated to question with the details

Comment: Is your id column auto incrementing in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA didn't find `Order` inside `orderLineItems` thats why `order_id` set as `null`. To save child with parent in the bidirectional relationship set parent in child entity also to sync both side.

```
public Order createOrder(Order order) {
       for(OrderLineItem orderLineItem : order.getOrderLineItems()) {
           orderLineItem.setOrder(order);
       }
       return this.orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  same problem. It is enough to add annotation:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

to save its children with parent saving without any other consideration.